# Sitecore and TDS Local development strategy

Tags: tds, sitecore-rocks

In the isolated development approach, I would like to make sure that "Build Solution" does not deploy TDS projects via TdsGlobal.config settings.  So far, I am not seeing immediately how to do that.
The only thing that comes to mind is to uncheck "Build" setting under Configuration Manager for a my "Debug" Configuration.  However, that will prevent TDS validations or other processing I may still want to happen at the build time.
Anyone can share how they set up their isolated environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that is right. The TDS projects will only deploy TDS to your website if you select `Deploy Solution` from the solution menu. In that can you can remove the deploy column checkbox from the configuration menu.

[image]

Comment: That's what I thought it should NOT do, but when i review the build log from msbuild "build" task, i see that the associated web projects are compiled and pushed to the TDS project output, and then /bin/**  does get deployed to the configured inetpub location.

Comment: What version on tds are you on?

Comment: I see this behavior with 5.6.0.14 and 5.6.0.15

Comment: This is still a weird issue and I am seeing this in 5.7.0.7.  When I cracked open the HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets, i see that Build Target invokes  DoTDSBuild which then invokes SitecoreWebProjectDeploy target.    This is a bit counter intuitive.